# Python converting cURL into POST request is returning an error of 414

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I am trying to convert a cURL request into a python POST request.

Here is the cURL:

```
curl -X POST -F xls_file=@/path/to/form.xls https://api.ona.io/api/v1/forms
```

And here is the python script that I've been working on:

```
with open(param_build_dir+'panther_test.xls', 'rb') as form:
        # xls = form.read()
        response = requests.post(ona_post_base_api, params={'xls_file': form}, headers = headers, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password))
        print(response.status_code)
        print(response.reason)
        print(response.text)
```

When we uncomment the part of `xls = form.read()`, the following error occured:

> Status code: 400
>
> Reason: Bad Request
>
> Text:
>
> {"type":"alert-error","text":"["XLSForm not provided, expecting
> either of these params: 'xml_file', 'xls_file',  'xls_url', 'csv_url',
> 'dropbox_xls_url', 'text_xls_form', 'floip_file'"]"}

Once commented, we receive the following error:

> Status Code: 414, Request-URI Too Large

Comment: You're looking for the `files` argument, not `params`…!? https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file

Comment: @deceze didn't work. i tried it with xls_file and file and in both cases didn't work:
`file = {'xls_file': open(param_build_dir+'panther_test.xls', 'rb')}`;

`response = requests.post(ona_post_base_api, files = file, headers = headers, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password))`

Answer (score 0):

I think

```py
import requests

files = {
    'xls_file': open('/path/to/form.xls', 'rb'),
}

response = requests.post('https://api.ona.io/api/v1/forms', files=files)
```

should work.

[resource](https://curlconverter.com/)